# Spring Pageable Sort works incorrect with mongoOperations. Sort order isn't correct

Tags: java, spring-boot, sorting, mongodb-query

I use `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable` to get pagination and sorting rules from Front-End. I need to sort the entries by name, at first glance everything is working correctly now. But, the system gives the character `I` before the character `f`. It looks as if the sorting is going well according to table ASCII.

```
011
Alpha
Itext
front
man
```

Request looks like `...&sort=title,desc`. I get an pagination object and put it in a query in the DB.

```java
return mongoOperations.find(Query.query(criteria).with(pageable), Book.class);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is working as intended, it sorts by name case sensitive.
You can change the sorting algorithm for example using the following code:

```java
Sort.Order order = new Sort.Order(Direction.ASC, "title").ignoreCase();
Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(page, pageSize, Sort.by(order));
Page<Video> findAll = videoRepo.findAll(paging);
```

You can use something like this to change the paging you get from your request and making it case insensitive:

```java
Pageable paging = ... // from your request

List<Order> caseInsensitiveOrders = paging.getSort().get().map(Order::ignoreCase).collect(Collectors.toList());
Pageable newPaging = PageRequest.of(page, pageSize, Sort.by(caseInsensitiveOrders));
Page<Video> findAll = videoRepo.findAll(newPaging);
```

The key is using `order.ignoreCase();`